# Can't we downcast int to boolean?

Tags: java

As per my understanding, 0 is being treated as `int` by default in line 1. This is why assigning `int` to `boolean` is giving compile time error. Is it correct? Also, why is it giving compile error in line 2, even upon explicit down-casting?

```
public class HelloWorld
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    boolean b = 0;         //1.compile time error
    boolean b = (boolean)0;//2.still compile time error
    System.out.print(b);
  }
}
```

Comment: Java is not C/C++ and a number is not a boolean. Hence no casting.

Comment: If you _really_ want to convert them, it's not hard to write a quick method to do it for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Java doesn't support conversion from `int` to `boolean`. This is because a `boolean` is not a number type in Java.

The idiomatic way is to write code of the form

`boolean b = n != 0;`

where `n` is a numeric type.

This is covered in [JLS§4.2.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.5):

> An integer or floating-point expression x can be converted to a boolean value, following the C language convention that any nonzero value is true, by the expression `x!=0`.
>
> ...
>
> A `boolean` value may be cast to type `boolean`, `Boolean`, or `Object` (§5.5). No other casts on type `boolean` are allowed.

Comment: It's basically the same as with strings: you just cannot cast a number to a string or vice versa since you'd change the type of the value and not just the precision/representation (e.g. like casting int to double). To do that you'd use an explicit expression/method to tell the compiler what that conversion would look like, much like `x!=0`. - One could say that casting `int` to `char` is allowed but one could also say that `char` is just a different representation of a number, i.e. the character's code point.